# C++ How to execute 2 and more query commands?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

IDE: VS 2013

I'm using .net connector (it's added as reference - "MySQL.Data"), how to execute more than one command in same time?

Code:

```
    int member = 0;
    String^ constring = L"datasource=localhost; port=3306; username=root; password=password";
    MySqlConnection^ conDatabase = gcnew MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand^ cmdDatabase = gcnew MySqlCommand("select * from users where nick = '" + this->label_nick->Text+ "'; ", conDatabase);
    MySqlDataReader^ myReader;
    try
    {
        conDatabase->Open();
        myReader = cmdDatabase->ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader->Read())
        {
            member++;
        }
        if (member == 1)
        {
            MessageBox::Show("Logged", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons::OK);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception^ex){
        MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place semicolons between each command.

http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/MultiQuery.html

**Edit**

Quote from www.devart.com

As a result of the execution you get open data reader positioned on the first result of the query. Call `MySqlDataReader.NextResult` method to advance to the next result. If you set `MySqlCommand.FetchAll property` to `true` you can reach any result using `MySqlDataReader.CurrentResult` and `MySqlDataReader.ResultCount` properties.